# Can "Attic Insulation" vermiculite be used in the garden?

Tags: square-foot-gardening, vermiculite

I'm looking for sources for vermiculite to try out a bit of square foot gardening this season.  I found one at [menards](https://www.menards.com/main/building-materials/insulation/loose-fill-insulation/micaflake-vermiculite-insulation/p-1444444167358.htm) but it says it's for attic insulation.  It also says there's no formaldehyde (which I guess is a little bit of a low bar for organic gardening) but is there any reason to think that I can't use this for making the "Mel's Mix"?

Seems like I need a lot of vermiculite to do it and this is one of my only local options.

Comment: What grade is it?  Should be coarse.  Also, older vermiculite used in insulation contained asbestos.  Try hydroponics shop for alternatives.

Comment: I found a blog from 10 years ago where someone used this brand.  They had a picture of it opened and it looked pretty course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mines that were responsible for supplying the asbestos contaminated vermiculite for home insulation were closed long ago so it's a problem for old home owners.  I would suggest not recycling that vermiculite for SFG use.

Some USA big box stores do carry vermiculite but it's likely to be medium rather than coarse grade.

[image: Home Depot vermiculite]

and what you're after is the coarse grade as it holds more water.  If they don't specify the grade, you can check by sizing.  Look for 4-8 mm size or higher.

[image]

http://www.vermiculite.com/

Answer (score -1):

Vermiculite , as I know it, is expanded mica, no asbestos . An inert mineral, Wikipedia must have some more information.

Comment: Opps ! I see on Wiki that years ago , asbestos was added to some vermiculite products.

Comment: Asbestos in home insulation vermiculite has been a huge problem.